# Blank ListView with multi-table SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, listview, android-layout

I'm trying to populate a ListView with data from a relational database.  What I am trying to accomplish is to show each nurse in NURSE_TABLE, and the room numbers that have been assigned to that nurse.  What I'm getting as a result is the layout showing the two buttons, and an empty ListView.

The code to create the database is:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// create NURSE_TABLE
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + NURSE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_NURSE_ROWID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +          KEY_LNAME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_MI + " TEXT, " + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_PHONE_PRIMARY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_PHONE_SECONDARY + " TEXT, " + KEY_FTE
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DUTY_STATUS + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

// create ROOM_TABLE
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ROOM_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROOM_ROWID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TYPE_PATIENT
        + " TEXT, " + KEY_OCCUPIED + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_ROOM_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_ASSIGNED_NURSE + " INTEGER, " 
        + " FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_ASSIGNED_NURSE + ") REFERENCES " 
        + NURSE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_NURSE_ROWID + "));");
    } // onCreate
```

The code for the activity is:

```
public void displayNurseRoster(){

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // int variables filled with NURSE_TABLE data
    int[] to_nurseTable = new int[] {

            // int list for data from NURSE_TABLE fields
            R.id.rosterDutyStatus,
            R.id.rosterListLname, 
            R.id.rosterListFname, 
            R.id.rosterListMI, 
            R.id.rosterListID,

            // int list for data from ROOM_ROWID fields
            R.id.firstAssignment,
            R.id.secondAssignment,
            R.id.thirdAssignment,
            R.id.fourthAssignment,
            R.id.fifthAssignment,
            R.id.sixthAssignment };

    // String array holding data fields from NURSE_TABLE 
    String[] from_nurseTable = new String [] {

            // fields from NURSE_TABLE
            DbCommunicator.KEY_DUTY_STATUS,
            DbCommunicator.KEY_LNAME, 
            DbCommunicator.KEY_FNAME, 
            DbCommunicator.KEY_MI,
            DbCommunicator.KEY_NURSE_ROWID,
            DbCommunicator.KEY_ROOM_NUMBER}; 

    // instantiate instance of DbCommunicator object
    rosterView = new DbCommunicator(this);

    // open instance
    rosterView.open();

    // get & manage cursor for NURSE_TABLE data
    Cursor nurseTableCursor = rosterView.getNurseRosterCursor(this);
    startManagingCursor(nurseTableCursor);

    // instantiate cursor adaptor
    ListAdapter nurseTableAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    R.layout.nurse_list, nurseTableCursor, from_nurseTable, to_nurseTable);

    nurseTableCursor.moveToNext();

    // set adapter to listView
    listView.setAdapter(nurseTableAdapter);
}// displayNurseRoster()
```

The code to generate the Cursor looks like this:

```
public Cursor getNurseRosterCursor (Context context) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder nurseQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    nurseQueryBuilder.setTables("NURSE_TABLE, ROOM_TABLE"); 

    String[] returnedColumns = new String[] {
            "Nurse_Table._id", 
            "Nurse_Table._dutyStatus",
            "Nurse_Table._lName",
            "Nurse_Table._FName",
            "Nurse_Table._mi",
            "Room_Table._id",
            "Room_Table._roomNumber"};

    Cursor nurseCursor = nurseQueryBuilder.query(sqldb, returnedColumns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    return nurseCursor;
}
```

And finally my layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#81BEF7"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddNurseToRoster"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add" 
    android:focusable="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRemoveNurseFromRoster"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnAddNurseToRoster"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAddNurseToRoster"
    android:text="@string/delete" 
    android:focusable="true"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddNurseToRoster"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I initially started, I was just populating the ListView with data from Nurses Table, which worked great, but have had a helluva time since I started trying to get the two tables to work together.

Any help / direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The layout comes up with the two buttons at the top, but the listview is completely empty.  I see no errors on logcat

Comment: Please put this information into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two table in your `setTables()` call are not properly joined.

The `from_nurseTable` and `to_nurseTable` arrays do not match.

You have not mentioned what you want to show in the list view, but I'd guess it might be something like the result of this query:

```
SELECT nurse_table._id,_dutyStatus,_lName,_FName,_mi,group_concat(_roomNumber)
  FROM nurse_table LEFT JOIN room_table ON nurse_table._id = _assignedNurse
  GROUP BY nurse_table._id
  ORDER BY _lName,_FName /* or whatever */
```

---

When you do not know how to construct your SQL query, it is often more helpful to test queries in a copy of the database on your desktop. (There are many SQLite administrations tools, or as last restort use the sqlite(.exe) command-line tool.)

Comment: What I'm trying to display is something like this:

Comment: ON DUTY      Johnson     Robin     R (next line) Tasks:   Rm 1    Rm 2

Comment: But I'm struggling with how to show that, since the number of rooms may change between one nurse to another.  Thanks for the response, I'm looking into how to properly join the tables.

Comment: Your `returnedColumns[]` has a "_id" field, so I assumed this to be the value of `KEY_NURSE_ROWID`. Without a **LEFT** join, nurses without rooms won't show up (which may or may not be what you want). GROUP BY does not make sense without using some aggregation function.

Comment: nurseQueryBuilder.setTables("Nurse_Table JOIN Room_Table ON Room_Table.Nurse_id = Nurse_Table._id");  This code seems to be working, and the problem I'm having is that if there are no room numbers assigned to nurses (Nurse_id fields are empty).  What I'm trying to do is to 1) show all nurses entered into the Nurse_Table, and 2) any rows in Room_Table where the Nurse_id field matches Nurse_Table._id field.  What I'm pretty sure is happening is that because there are no rooms in the table at start up, everything is blank.

Comment: You are exactly right in that is want:  A ListView of all nurses in the Nurse_Table and any _roomNumbers where the Nurse_id field matches Nurse_Table._id.  That said, if I make the above statement a LEFT JOIN it should work, but for whatever reason I have not yet been able to figure out, when I try to use a join statement in the querybuilder, I just get an empty listview

Comment: Got it working.  Just some newbie syntax errors.  I still have a problem though and any advise would be appreciated.   Because a nurse may be assigned up to six tasks, the ListView contains six possible assignments, but since each assignment is populated from a different record from the Room_Table I get a force close.  I understand why it isn't working, but am unsure of what direction to go to fix.